# How to signal all listeners

Tags: c++, winapi, ipc, mutex, waitforsingleobject

I have several processes in my application. One writes to shared memory while other listen to global named mutex using WaitForSingleObject. When I call ReleaseMutex in writer process this wakes up only one listener.

I need somehow to signal all processes once the write operation is complete. 
Is there any way to wakeup all listeners, like pulseall in c#?

Comment: Well, mutex stands for "mutually exclusive". By definition, only one thread at a time can own a mutex. If you need to release multiple listeners, you are using a wrong synchronization primitive. You probably want an event (see `CreateEvent`).

Comment: Indeed  a handle from CreateEvent can be shared by multiple processes. Thank you very much. I'll try it.